# Fetching a struct and other data in one query

Tags: database, postgresql, go, orm, go-gorm

I have the following table schema:

```
user
-----
id uuid
name string

user_model
------
id uuid
user_id uuid
model_id uuid
role int

model
_____
id uuid
name string
model_no string
```

I have the following code which fetches the data from the "model" table.

```
underlyingModel = &model{}
var model IModel
model = underlyingModel
role := 0

db.Table("model").Joins('INNER JOIN user_model ON user.id = user_model.uuid')
.Joins('INNER JOIN model ON user.id = model_id').Find(&model);
```

In my actual code, the model can be many different struct types with different fields, they're all behind the `IModel` interface.

What I want to do is to fetch that extra `role` field from the `user_model` in one query. Something like `.Find(&model, &role)`.

Is it possible using Gorm?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create an anonymous struct to put the results in, with a combination of the `Select()` method.

```
var selectModel struct {
   ID string //I'm assuming uuid matches the string
   Name string
   ModelNo string
   Role int
}

db.Table("model").
   Joins("INNER JOIN user_model ON user.id = user_model.uuid").
   Joins("INNER JOIN model ON user.id = model_id").
   Select("model.id, model.name, model.model_no, user_model.role").
   Find(&selectModel);
```

Basically, you create an anonymous struct with `selectModel` variable, containing all the fields you want to return. Then, you need to do a select statement because you need some fields that are not part of the `model` table.

[Here](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#Smart-Select-Fields) you can find more info on Smart Select Fields in form.

**EDIT:**

Based on additional info from the comments, there is a solution that might work.

Your `IModel` interface could have two methods in its signature, one to extract a string for the `SELECT` part of the SQL query, and the other one to get a pointer of the `selectModel` that you would use in the `Find` method.

```
type IModel interface {
  SelectFields() string
  GetSelectModel() interface{}
}
```

The implementation would go something like this:

```
func (m *model) SelectFields() string {
  return "model.id, model.name, model.model_no, user_model.role"
}

func (m *model) GetSelectModel() interface{} {
  return &m.selectModel
}

type model struct {
 selectModel
 ID uint64
 Age int
}


type selectModel struct {
  Name string
  Email string
}
```

Then, your query could look something like this:

```
   var m IModel
   m = model{}

   db.Table("model").
   Joins("INNER JOIN user_model ON user.id = user_model.uuid").
   Joins("INNER JOIN model ON user.id = model_id").
   Select(m.GetSelectFields()).
   Find(m.GetSelectModel());
```

Comment: I can't name it out id, name, modelno like you did there because I wouldn't know the name of the field in advance, it may be different depending on which. I wonder if I can use a struct embedding, embed an `IModel` interface inside a `selectModel`.

Comment: Can `IModel` have a `SelectFields` method (or something similar), that would provide a list of fields that need to be added to the SQL `SELECT` statement?

Comment: I'm guessing Gorm probably has something like that to be able to do its ORM magic, but I do not understand its code. And I rely its magic specifically for this purpose, so my CRUD operations can be made oblivious to the type of model. I tried embedding an IModel which is created using reflection and embed it to a struct with the Role but it didn't work. I guess I'll do two queries for the time being. Thanks for the help.

Comment: the first example worked. the struct should just have the `db:"id"` table colums that you are expecting from the query and you will be fine. the editted section is just an overkill.